# Does this inequality guarantee the global stability in this paper?

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, lyapunov-functions

I'm reading [a very informative paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8794351?casa_token=ae6n4UMp3PMAAAAA:6CMvOBfrGuthgxyppnXDcqn-pRGp7yP2FnT7jw9ItbfSfvkb_Yy6qjunmnZr1VNXhme_0b7QGA). But I met some formulations hard to understand.

In the stability proof section (Sec. V, Theorem 5.2), they define a Lyapunov function as $V(s) = \frac{1}{2}m\|s\|^2$ and obtain the resulting inequality:

$\|s(t)\|\leq \|s(t_0)\|\exp(-\frac{\lambda-L_a\rho}{m}(t-t_0))+\frac{\epsilon_m}{\lambda-L_a\rho}$

I understand when $\frac{\lambda-L_a\rho}{m}>0$, $\|s(t)\|\rightarrow \frac{\epsilon_m}{\lambda-L_a\rho}$ thus it's stable.

However, the problem seems that the in $Assumption 3$ they assume the upper bound $\epsilon_m$ exists in a compact set $\mathcal{X}$, meaning the result is only valid in the set, not globally.

Moreover, since they just assume $\epsilon$ has upper bound within the compact set and their result directly has the $\epsilon_m$ term, it seems also necessary to show the states always stays in the compact set. And to me, such statement seems missing

Please help me understand why this inequality and the assumption guarantee the global stability.

*FYI, I asked them this question directly 2 month ago (plus the reminder 2 weeks ago) and I do not have the reply yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Assumption 3 places a bound on the *learning error* of the map $\hat f_a$ that maps control actions & states to the unknown translational force. It is the translational force they are trying to predict in order to effectively cancel out its effects when doing position tracking.

The training *does not* happen while the controller is running, so basically they are saying that they can train this map $\hat f_a$ to be within some reasonable upper bound of error $\epsilon_m$ away from the true disturbance force $f_a$. This then appears in the stability proof as a constant (obviously) since any error in predicted translational force acts as an obstruction to asymptotic stability. The more accurate the model is trained, the closer the convergence of the controller will be because we can more closely predict and cancel the predictable disturbance forces (e.g. ground effect).

I haven't checked every single detail of the proof to be fair, but under the presented assumptions I can imagine a global stability result could exist. After all, the paper is learning certain disturbance forces and cancelling them out with feedback linearization; so if you can learn it well, then yeah a global (for an appropriate sense of global) result is feasible. Of course, if somewhere else they restrict the state to a compact set, sure, but I can't find that.

Comment: Thank you sir. I appreciate your summary and explanation. I see...if I understand your answer correctly, my concern is only valid for the case where training is done while the controller is running?

Comment: I mean, if the DNN is real-time trained, it will be needed to state the controller never goes out of a set where the upper bound of the learning error exists.

Comment: @SpaceTAKA Yes. If you are trying to learn the map while controlling the system, the Assumption doesn't apply and you have to prove that $\hat f_a$ itself converges to $f_a$ within $\epsilon_m$ as part of the same proof that shows the state converges.

Comment: Thank you. Well, to prove that, it seems necessary to have some kind of prior knowledge on the $f_a$ structure such as the Lipschitz constant of $f_a$ is under that of $\hat{f}_a$ (But I have no idea how to show the convergence from this). Do you have any tips for it? Anyway, I'll choose your answer for this post, thank you

Comment: @SpaceTAKA Off the top of my head, I'd suggest diving into the literature on using RL in-the-loop. That is kind of the point of RL in control (to learn while controlling the system). These days there are always a few papers in control conferences on that.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, I'll check these papers and try to define a proper assumption of  unknown disturbance to guarantee the stability

Comment: If you know an example of  RL in-the-loop paper, please share with me. It'll be  great  help to know about the community (such as keyword, conference)

Comment: And what you meant by RL? Real-time Learning or Reinforcement Learning etc